# SQL Join Issue, Doing Something Really Wrong With Self Joins?

Tags: sql, join

Okay, so I am trying to get a given output in SQL to list a custom quarter value along with an accounts given activation and termination date. My company uses an off-standard quarter reckoning so I created a little schema matching the custom quarter recognition to standard months. The query works great until i try to get the thing to also include the termination quarter as well.

I am going to use this as a view and generate a report from its results. Here is the query thus far. I recognize that I am not very good SQL yet so i am trying hard to use best practices and easily readable code. Please feel free to critique anything at all or perhaps suggest a more efficient way of achieving my goal.

```
SELECT ZoneA.ZoneDescription
        ,TrackerA.Zone
        ,MasterListA.Name
        ,SubscriptionsA.ActivationDate
        ,SubscriptionsA.TerminationDate
        ,ParentA.ProductParentType
        ,MONTH(SubscriptionsA.ActivationDate) AS ActivationMonth
        ,MONTH(SubscriptionsA.TerminationDate) AS TerminationMonth
        ,QuartersA.CompanyFiscalQuarter AS ActivationQuarter
        ,QuartersB.CompanyFiscalQuarter AS TerminationQuarter
FROM BalanceTracker.Zone AS ZoneA INNER JOIN
        BalanceTracker.TrackerAccounts AS TrackerA ON ZoneA.ZoneID = TrackerA.Zone INNER JOIN
        BalanceTracker.SweepAccounts AS SweepA ON TrackerA.TrackedAccount = SweepA.SweepAccount INNER JOIN
        Fed.MasterAccountList AS MasterListA ON SweepA.MasterAccountListID = MasterListA.MasterAccountListID INNER JOIN
        Products.Subscriptions AS SubscriptionsA ON MasterListA.MasterAccountListID = SubscriptionsA.SnlId INNER JOIN
        Products.ProductParent AS ParentA ON SubscriptionsA.ProductCode = ParentA.ProductCode INNER JOIN
        Calendar.Quarters AS QuartersA ON SubscriptionsA.ActivationMonth = QuartersA.MonthNumber,
        Products.Subscriptions AS SubscriptionsB INNER JOIN
        Calendar.Quarters AS QuartersB ON SubscriptionsB.TerminationMonth = QuartersB.CompanyFiscalQuarter
ORDER BY TrackerA.Zone, SubscriptionsA.ActivationDate
```

Tables are as follows:

-Zone: ZoneID (PK)
-TrackerAccounts: Tracked Account (PK), Zone (FK)
-SweepAccounts: SweepAccount (PK, FK on TrackerAccounts), MasterAccountListId (FK on MasterAccountList)
-MasterAccountList: MasterAccountListId (PK)
-Subscriptions: SubscriptionId (PK), SnlId (FK on MasterAccountList), ProductCode (FK on ProductParent)
-ProductParent: ProductCode (PK)

### -Quarters: MonthNumber (PK)

Comment: What exactly is your problem/question?

Comment: Additionally, which SQL... SQL-Server, MySQL, Oracle...

Comment: Oops. Just notice these detail questions from you guys. Sorry. @Tom, My problem is/was that i was getting a huge number of results that were not expected. @DRapp, I am using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you say `, Products.Subscriptions AS SubscriptionsB` you're doing a cross join, so it's going to output NxN rows where N is the total number of subscriptions. I doubt you need that join at all, since you don't appear to be using any values from that instance i.e this should work just fine:

```
SELECT ZoneA.ZoneDescription
        ,TrackerA.Zone
        ,MasterListA.Name
        ,SubscriptionsA.ActivationDate
        ,SubscriptionsA.TerminationDate
        ,ParentA.ProductParentType
        ,MONTH(SubscriptionsA.ActivationDate) AS ActivationMonth
        ,MONTH(SubscriptionsA.TerminationDate) AS TerminationMonth
        ,QuartersA.CompanyFiscalQuarter AS ActivationQuarter
        ,QuartersB.CompanyFiscalQuarter AS TerminationQuarter
FROM BalanceTracker.Zone AS ZoneA INNER JOIN
        BalanceTracker.TrackerAccounts AS TrackerA ON ZoneA.ZoneID = TrackerA.Zone INNER JOIN
        BalanceTracker.SweepAccounts AS SweepA ON TrackerA.TrackedAccount = SweepA.SweepAccount INNER JOIN
        Fed.MasterAccountList AS MasterListA ON SweepA.MasterAccountListID = MasterListA.MasterAccountListID INNER JOIN
        Products.Subscriptions AS SubscriptionsA ON MasterListA.MasterAccountListID = SubscriptionsA.SnlId INNER JOIN
        Products.ProductParent AS ParentA ON SubscriptionsA.ProductCode = ParentA.ProductCode INNER JOIN
        Calendar.Quarters AS QuartersA ON SubscriptionsA.ActivationMonth = QuartersA.MonthNumber LEFT JOIN
        Calendar.Quarters AS QuartersB ON SubscriptionsA.TerminationMonth = QuartersB.CompanyFiscalQuarter
ORDER BY TrackerA.Zone, SubscriptionsA.ActivationDate
```

Comment: @mootinator: But he uses the `QuartersB.CompanyFiscalQuarter` in the SELECT list and `QuartersB` table is joined through `SubscriptionsB`. So, he needs that table.

Comment: @mootinator. Awesome results but it has narrowed down my table to about a quarter of the size it needs to be. Apparently it is only returning records that have a termination date and thus quarter. In actuality I need it to return records that also have NULLS for values in TerminationMonth.

Comment: @ypercube I see no evidence that the OP needed to get TerminationMonth from a different subscription record than ActivationMonth, unless the OP wants subscriptions which aren't terminated yet to appear in the results, in which case the OP should use LEFT join on QuartersB, but if that is the problem, the OP should say so.

Comment: @ZenTechInc Ha, whoops, okay, I updated my answer to use `LEFT JOIN` for the termination date. :)

Comment: @mmotinator: I agree, you have a point here. We can't really know, unless @Zen provides at least the relations between the tables and a description of what he wants the query to show.

Comment: @ZenTechInc: Another thought. Are you sure the last join condition: `ON SubscriptionsB.TerminationMonth = QuartersB.CompanyFiscalQuarter` is the right one? It doesn't seem right a `Month` to be related to a `FiscalQuarter`.

Comment: @mootinator: Thanks so much for your help, I am comparing your statement side by side with my original and it is helping to clarify things for me. However, I am still getting unexpected results in that the entire subscription table I am testing on is only about 2907 rows and the return results given with your tweaked query is giving 3244 results. Not possible unless I have a mixed up join somewhere right?

Comment: In regard to your last question about the month being related to the quarter, I suppose my logic could be wrong somewhere, but i don't know where. The way the Quarters table works is that it has 12 records (1 for each calendar month) along with the seasonal quarter as well as the company's reckoning of whatever quarter corresponds to said month. So January (month 1) would read: 1, January, 1, 4; Where the columns are MonthNumber, MonthName, SeasonalQuarter, CompanyFiscalQuarter.

Comment: @ZenTechInc That will happen anytime two tables are joined on a non-unique key.  It's really hard to say where you've done that without knowing more about the database structure.

Comment: @ZenTechInc Just from experience though, it could be the ProductParent table.  If any products have more than one ProductParentType (For instance if the product was a lawnmower it might have types 'seasonal' and 'tools') you will get a separate row for each ProductParentType associated with the product.

Answer (score 1):

Reformatted for me to get readability... You don't have a join condition to your second "Subscriptions" which would create a Cartesian join... Other than that, your query structure looks fine (overall)

```
SELECT 
      ZoneA.ZoneDescription
      ,TrackerA.Zone
      ,MasterListA.Name
      ,SubscriptionsA.ActivationDate
      ,SubscriptionsA.TerminationDate
      ,ParentA.ProductParentType
      ,MONTH(SubscriptionsA.ActivationDate) AS ActivationMonth
      ,MONTH(SubscriptionsA.TerminationDate) AS TerminationMonth
      ,QuartersA.CompanyFiscalQuarter AS ActivationQuarter
      ,QuartersB.CompanyFiscalQuarter AS TerminationQuarter
FROM 
   BalanceTracker.Zone AS ZoneA 
      INNER JOIN BalanceTracker.TrackerAccounts AS TrackerA 
         ON ZoneA.ZoneID = TrackerA.Zone 
         INNER JOIN BalanceTracker.SweepAccounts AS SweepA 
            ON TrackerA.TrackedAccount = SweepA.SweepAccount 
            INNER JOIN Fed.MasterAccountList AS MasterListA 
               ON SweepA.MasterAccountListID = MasterListA.MasterAccountListID 
               INNER JOIN Products.Subscriptions AS SubscriptionsA 
                  ON MasterListA.MasterAccountListID = SubscriptionsA.SnlId 
                  INNER JOIN Products.ProductParent AS ParentA 
                     ON SubscriptionsA.ProductCode = ParentA.ProductCode 
                  INNER JOIN Calendar.Quarters AS QuartersA 
                     ON SubscriptionsA.ActivationMonth = QuartersA.MonthNumber
                  INNER JOIN Calendar.Quarters AS QuartersB 
                     ON SubscriptionsA.TerminationMonth= QuartersB.CompanyFiscalQuarter    
ORDER BY 
   TrackerA.Zone, 
   SubscriptionsA.ActivationDate
```

Comment: I know what you mean about missing something right there but i couldn't figure out how to express how to re-reference the Subscriptions table again with a join on Quarters from a different column. Should there have been an AND statement in there?

Comment: @ZenTechInc, as long as it's a different alias of the same sub-table (Quarters A vs B), you can join on any table... I've adjusted the query to finish based on the termination month for you... Check it out.

Comment: Nailed down so the query doesn't give NxN results, but I am getting too few results now. The query needs to return records that have NULL values for Termination Date as well. It was suggested above that a left join for the last portion be used. This allows the query to return the NULLS as well but for some reason it is now returning more rows than actually exist within the table.

Comment: @ZenTechInc,  based on your last comment (I was out for a meeting... delay)... Add a single row to your "Quarters" table with a NULL value for the Company Fiscal Quarter.  This way, the join will complete based on a valid "NULL" value.  The NORMAL join should find the single record to be returned since you state... Otherwise, where are the multiples coming in...  The only thing I can think of are multiple entries somewhere up the chain of your relationships down to subscriptions...

Comment: @ZenTechInc, I would try querying one level at a time to find out where the duplicates are slipping in.... then either tighten the join condition to get only one per level, or purge the duplicates... or figure out another resolution to them...

Answer (score 1):

Juat a guess that the last condition could be a join on `QuartersB.MonthNumber` and not on `QuartersB.CompanyFiscalQuarter`:

```
     Calendar.Quarters AS QuartersB 
         ON SubscriptionsA.TerminationMonth = QuartersB.MonthNumber
```

You can also change the last join into a `LEFT JOIN` if as you say the `TerminationMonth` can be `NULL`.

```
SELECT 
      ZoneA.ZoneDescription
    , TrackerA.Zone
    , MasterListA.Name
    , SubscriptionsA.ActivationDate
    , SubscriptionsA.TerminationDate
    , ParentA.ProductParentType
    , MONTH(SubscriptionsA.ActivationDate) AS ActivationMonth
    , MONTH(SubscriptionsA.TerminationDate) AS TerminationMonth
    , QuartersA.CompanyFiscalQuarter AS ActivationQuarter
    , QuartersB.CompanyFiscalQuarter AS TerminationQuarter
FROM 
     BalanceTracker.Zone AS ZoneA  INNER JOIN
     BalanceTracker.TrackerAccounts AS TrackerA 
         ON ZoneA.ZoneID = TrackerA.Zone  INNER JOIN
     BalanceTracker.SweepAccounts AS SweepA 
         ON TrackerA.TrackedAccount = SweepA.SweepAccount  INNER JOIN
     Fed.MasterAccountList AS MasterListA 
         ON SweepA.MasterAccountListID = MasterListA.MasterAccountListID  INNER JOIN 
     Products.Subscriptions AS SubscriptionsA 
         ON MasterListA.MasterAccountListID = SubscriptionsA.SnlId  INNER JOIN 
     Products.ProductParent AS ParentA 
         ON SubscriptionsA.ProductCode = ParentA.ProductCode  INNER JOIN 
     Calendar.Quarters AS QuartersA 
         ON SubscriptionsA.ActivationMonth = QuartersA.MonthNumber  INNER JOIN 
     Calendar.Quarters AS QuartersB 
         ON SubscriptionsA.TerminationMonth = QuartersB.MonthNumber  
ORDER BY 
      TrackerA.Zone 
    , SubscriptionsA.ActivationDate
```

Comment: Bingo. I am getting the same number of results with your query as i am when i ignore the TerminationQuarter all together. However, I did have to change your last join to a left join as suggested by mootinator above. Can you explain what lead you to your changes?

Comment: I just noticed that you joined using a `sometable.Month = someothertable.FiscalQuarter`. It didn't seem right.

Comment: So i could be blind or dumb, but it just appears that all you did was change the last join to ... ON SubscriptionsA.TerminationMonth from SubscriptionsB.TerminationMonth. Correct?

Comment: Yes, and removed the `, Products.Subscriptions AS SubscriptionsB` as @mootinator advised. You should cast the correct answer to him I think.

Comment: And as a final advice, it would be good to edit the question and add at the end the tables, fields and foreign key relations. There could be other logic errors in the query but we can't know without this info.